# What is the best similarity metric for bottleneck features of images extracted from a pre-trained neural network?

Tags: conv-neural-network, k-nearest-neighbour, cosine-similarity

I have a bunch of images and a pre-trained **AlexNet** model. I have fetched bottleneck features for all images as their representations. I want to find top-K similar images for a given image. What similarity metric (e.g. `cosine similarity`) is best suited for finding similar images given their bottleneck features?

Answer (score 1):

Among some commonly used metrics, I often found Euclidean like distances work better than cosine similarity in such tasks.

To find the best suited similarity metric is actually a research topic known as [metric learning](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=metric%20learning&oq=metric%20learning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i60l4.2671j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).